# C# Assign Name for Try-Catch Error

Tags: c#, error-handling, try-catch

Everybody use [Try-Catch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yd65esw.aspx) in C#. I know that.

For Example;

```
static void Main()
    {
        string s = null; // For demonstration purposes.

        try
        {            
            ProcessString(s);
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} Exception caught.", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Everything is OK.

But how can i assign name for spesific error?

For Example;

```
try
{
   enter username;
   enter E-Mail;
}
catch
{

}
```

- IF username is already exist, `ErrorMessage`--> ("The Username Already Exist")
- IF E-Mail is already exist, `ErrorMessage` --> ("E-Mail is using")

How can i do that in `C#`?

Best Regards,

Soner

Comment: Checking if a name already exists should not raise an exception IMO.

Comment: does the note intend that we can safely ignore this question !

Comment: @Brian: It could if something does mess up during the check, but, that's beside the point :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if(UserNameAlreadyExists(username))
{
   throw new Exception("Username already exists");
}
if(EmailAlreadyExists(email))
{
   throw new Exception("Email already exists");
}
```

This will answer your question.

But exception handling is not to be used to perform checks like those. Exceptions are costly, and are meant for exceptional circumstances where you can't recover from the error.

Answer (score 3):

When you throw exceptions you can assign messages to them:

```
throw new Exception("The username already exists");
```

But I don't think you should be throwing exceptions here, because your application is going to *expect* input that causes these errors; they're not *exceptional* conditions. Maybe you should use validators or some other kind of handler instead.

Comment: How can i use with this "throw new.." with ASP.NET Validators?

Answer (score 2):

```
try
{
    if (username exists)
    {
        throw new Exception("The Username Already Exist");
    }

    if (e-mail exists)
    {
        throw new Exception("The E-Mail Already Exist");
    }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("The Error is{0}", ex.Message);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think all these answers have a point towards the question, but if you at some point in the future want different handling per exception you'd do it as follows:

The next examples assumes you have two different exceptions implemented

```
try
{
    if user name is exit
    {
        throw new UserNameExistsException("The Username Already Exist");
    }

    if e-mail is already exit
    {
        throw new EmailExistsException("The E-Mail Already Exist");
    }
}
catch(UserNameExistsException ex)
{
    //Username specific handling
}
catch(EmailExistsException ex)
{
    //EMail specific handling
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    //All other exceptions come here!
    Console.WriteLine("The Error is{0}", ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: +1 for not missing the point. The OP's question itself is not entirely clear.. does he want custom error messages or a custom catch block per _type of error_

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
if (UsernameAlreadyExcists(username))
{
    throw new Exception("The Username Already Exist");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In C#, it is possible to create our own exception class. But Exception must be the ultimate base class for all exceptions in C#. So the user-defined exception classes must inherit from either Exception class or one of its standard derived classes.

```
using System;
class MyException : Exception
{
  public MyException(string str)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("User defined exception");
  }
}
class MyClass
{
  public static void Main()
  {
    try
    {
      throw new MyException("user exception");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Exception caught here" + e.ToString());
    }      
  }
}
```

You can throw these Exceptions and Catch them wherever in your App, although i wouldnt use Exceptions in this Case.